# Split json respond to separate arrays

Tags: javascript, json

my json respond is

`["2013,1,10,'Test Holiday'", "2013,1,31,'Staff Trip'", "2013,2,8,'Poya'"]`

i want to this covert as multiple arrays separate by main comma like

`[Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that none of the strings have additional commas in them, you could do:

```
response.map( function(x) { return x.split(",") } )
```

`map` applies a function to each of the elements of an array.  In this case, it splits each of the strings on the comma.

If indeed your strings could have commas in them, then you'll need to do some more parsing to figure out which ones you want to exclude.